# How to configure or get Chef::Client if I have a Chef::Node with the API alone

Tags: ruby, mongodb, chef-infra

I have chef, a workstation and some nodes provisioned through hosted chef.  I need to do some work on the nodes in a ruby script, not a cookbook/recipe, so I am using `Chef::Search` to query for them.

I have an array of `Chef::Nodes` in my script, and I want to get a handle on each node's chef-client so I can run a recipe on each one.  Remember I am NOT doing a regular chef run, but need to mimic what a chef run does:  pulls down the nodes, expands their `run_lists` and  run recipes on them as needed.

**Why?**
because, I am not just provisioning; I need to check the status of the nodes and select a particular one to run a recipe on.  The nodes are provisioned with mongo and they need maintenance as a replica set. I cannot run sequential recipes and I cannot run from one of the nodes.

**So my need is:**  given a `Chef::Node` that I got form a `Chef::Search::Query`, how does one get its `chef-client` or load it into a new `Chef::Client`?

I have extensively looked at the `API` and the `Chef::Client` class doesn't seem to be clearly telling me how.  There is initialize and loadNode but nothing that takes a node.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do a lot of what you are asking using [knife-exec](http://docs.opscode.com/knife_exec.html).  It allows you, if you have an API key, to manipulate data on a Chef server with a Ruby script.  This includes searches, nodes, roles and whatnot.  I mainly use it to to mass updates of attributes on large numbers of nodes instead of doing `knife node edit` by hand.

This doesn't answer how to run `chef-client` on nodes though.  Perhaps you could run "ssh node1 sudo chef-client" or use `knife-ssh` to do this.